# Parsing large images from facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get images from facebook graph api. The link provided for images in JSON file gives images of size 130x130.e.g. [here](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/11008613_915833678436988_798745067853775019_n.jpg?oh=db88808b316edcd26c7c39e2e5615fc3&oe=5572C7FA&__gda__=1433554568_aefee4820a6d5e073d0fd00bd386c341) I want to extract larger sizes,say 600x600. How do I do that?
Currently, I am getting images like this `imgUrl[i] = c.getString("picture");` and `myBitmap[i] = getBitmapFromUrl(imgUrl[i]);`

Comment: did you checked it ??

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem and nobody seems to know the answer, even in fb.
I think we should use differents methods to get each object picture realated to it's type. I've create a question but I got 2 down votes in less than 10 minutes
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233382/getting-large-images-from-facebook-with-graph-api-v2-2-by-typefeed-post-photo-l

Comment: I think the reason you got down-votes is because your question is quite unclear. You should directly get to the point. Anyways up voted your question :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to request from graph Api like me/picture?redirect=false&height=600&width=600
You will get response with image url size 600*600

You can visit [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture) also to get a greater insight

[image]

**Edit**
if you want picture from a page, try this way

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/pagename/picture?redirect=false&height=200&width=200&access_token=
```

Comment: Actually, I am getting url from JSON data of a page feeds, like this `pagename/feed`

Comment: Json data from web service you made ?

Comment: I am getting JSON data from url like this. `url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/pagename/feed?access_token="
   + static_token` When I parse images from the urls given in JSON data I get 130x130 size images

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/pagename/picture?redirect=false&height=200&width=200&access_token=

Comment: It'll give me only the profile picture of page. I need images from of the posts.